# Index was outside the bounds of the array c#, morse converter

Tags: c#, converters, morse-code

I was trying to build a Morse converter, the following is a part of my code of c#, but when I run it it tells me index out of the bounds, could anyone fix it? I'm new for programming:)

```
private void BTNconvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    string input = TBinput.Text;
    string[] output=new string[input.Length];
    for (int index=0;index<input.Length;index++)
    {
        index=input.IndexOf('a',index);
        output[index]=".-";                                               
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
    {
        index = input.IndexOf('b', index);
        output[index] = "-...";
    }

    LBcodes.Text = string.Join(" ",output);
```

Comment: index is zero-based. You should iterate to input.Lenght - 1.

Comment: Well. I thought by this way I can search the original string at the first element.

Comment: @user18044: He's checking that it's less than (`<`) input.Length, so that's not the problem.

Comment: could you explain more for me? Thanks

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Could you fix it for me?

Comment: @RobbieNirvanaLiu have a look at my answer it will solve your problem I think;

Comment: @RobbieNirvanaLiu did you try my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void BTNconvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
   int index;     
    string input = TBinput.Text;
    string[] output=new string[input.Length];
       index = -1;
        do{
             index=input.IndexOf('a',index+1);
             if(index==-1)break;
             output[index]=".-";     
        }while(true);
        index = -1;
        do{
             index=input.IndexOf('b',index+1);
             if(index==-1)break;
             output[index]="-...";     
        }while(true);
    }

    LBcodes.Text = string.Join(" ",output);
```

also if you are going to make these loops for all of the characters I would recommand you to do this:

```
private void BTNconvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  

   int index;
   char[] source1 = {'a','b','c',....,'z'} //replace ... with characters
   string[] source2 = {".-","-...",....}   //replace .... with Morse equivalents
    string input = TBinput.Text;
    string[] output=new string[input.Length];
       for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
       index = -1;
        do{
             index=input.IndexOf(source1[i],index+1);
             if(index==-1)break;
             output[index]=source2[i];     
        }while(true);
        }
    }

    LBcodes.Text = string.Join(" ",output);
```

Comment: with my codes I tried to type in a string with only a and b, it does not work either and same error occurs, if I take off the second for loop which search for 'b', and I only type in 'a's, it works.

Comment: I'm new to stack flow, I checked the button left to your answer, is it marked?

Comment: @RobbieNirvanaLiu yes it is. check second part of my answer I think it will help you even more.

Comment: I'm reading it, I think it also solve my future questions, I was thinking of calling a method, but I think this one works better. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're seeing this error is that `IndexOf()` will return a `-1` value if the given search term is not found in the string, so when you try to set `output[-1]` you end up with an invalid index.

Comment: It could be one reason that it's not working. I tried to type in a string with only a and b, it does not work either and same error occurs, if I take off the second for loop which search for 'b', and I only type in 'a's, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would keep a Dictionary mapping of each character and it's corresponding morse string. This will make it easy to convert back and forth.

For example:

```
private static Dictionary<char, string> MorseMap = new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    {'A', ".-"}, {'B', "-..."}, {'C', "-.-."}, {'D', "-.."},
    {'E', "."}, {'F', "..-."}, {'G', "--."}, {'H', "...."},
    {'I', ".."}, {'J', ".---"}, {'K', "-.-"}, {'L', ".-.."},
    {'M', "--"}, {'N', "-."}, {'O', "---"}, {'P', ".--."},
    {'Q', "--.-"}, {'R', ".-."}, {'S', "..."}, {'T', "-"},
    {'U', "..-"}, {'V', "...-"}, {'W', ".--"}, {'X', "-..-"},
    {'Y', "-.--"}, {'Z', "--.."},{'1', ".----"}, {'2', "..---"}, 
    {'3', "...--"}, {'4', "....-"},{'5', "....."}, {'6', "-...."}, 
    {'7', "--..."}, {'8', "---.."},{'9', "----."}, {'0', "-----"},
    {'.', ".-.-.-"}, {',', "--..--"},{'?', "..--.."}, {'\'', ".----."},
    {'!', "-.-.--"}, {'/', "-..-."},{'(', "-.--."}, {')', "-.--.-"},
    {'&', ".-..."}, {':', "---..."},{';', "-.-.-."}, {'=', "-...-"},
    {'+', ".-.-."}, {'-', "-....-"},{'_', "..--.-"}, {'"', ".-..-."},
    {'$', "...-..-"}, {'@', ".--.-."}
};
```

Now, using the keys and values from this map, it's fairly easy to encode and decode to morse:

```
private static string ConvertToMorse(string input)
{
    var morse = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var character in input)
    {
        var upperCaseChar = char.ToUpper(character);

        if (MorseMap.ContainsKey(upperCaseChar))
        {
            morse.Append(MorseMap[upperCaseChar]);
        }
        else
        {
            // If there's no mapping for this character, just add it
            morse.Append(character);
        }

        // Add a space between each morse string.
        morse.Append(' ');
    }

    return morse.ToString().Trim();
}

private static string ConvertToAlpha(string morse)
{
    var alpha = new StringBuilder();

    // Split words on double-spaces so we can add single spaces back where needed
    var morseCodeWords = morse.Split(new[] {"  "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (var morseCodeWord in morseCodeWords)
    {
        var morseCodeStrings = morseCodeWord.Split(' ');

        foreach (var morseCodeString in morseCodeStrings)
        {
            if (MorseMap.ContainsValue(morseCodeString))
            {
                alpha.Append(MorseMap.First(item => item.Value == morseCodeString).Key);
            }
            else
            {
                // If there's no mapping for the string, just add it
                alpha.Append(morseCodeString);
            }
        }

        // Add a space between each word
        alpha.Append(' ');
    }

    return alpha.ToString();
}
```

Usage Example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var test = "This is my test string.";

    var morseVersion = ConvertToMorse(test);
    var alphaVersion = ConvertToAlpha(morseVersion);

    Console.WriteLine("Original string ... {0}", test);
    Console.WriteLine("Morse version ..... {0}", morseVersion);
    Console.WriteLine("Alpha version ..... {0}", alphaVersion);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf() will return -1 if specified text not found in the input string. Your code will work fine only if you entering specified character in the text box. That's why your code works fine when you removed the second loop and enter all a's to text box.

In addition to that why you need to use 2 loops. You are doing the same thing in both loops.